# Getting error: HttpRequestException: Received an invalid header name: 'Content=Transfer-Encoding'. when using MVC Core to download a file

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core, webclient

I'm trying to have a controller in MVC core (3.1) download an audio file to present to the user but everything I try ends up with the error:

```
HttpRequestException: Received an invalid header name: 'Content=Transfer-Encoding'.
```

I have tried webclient, httpclient and just lately webrequest/webresponse. My code looks like this right now (specifics removed for security):

```
WebRequest downloadRequest = WebRequest.Create({url here});
            downloadRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", "{cookie data here};");
            downloadRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            downloadRequest.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0");
            downloadRequest.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
            downloadRequest.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

            using (WebResponse webResponse = await downloadRequest.GetResponseAsync())
            {

                 return File(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), "audio/wav", wavFile + ".txt");
            }
```

The error is on the line

```
 using (WebResponse webResponse = await downloadRequest.GetResponseAsync())
```

Using fiddler the request looks good and the header it is complaining about is: Content=Transfer-Encoding: binary, it has the file in the content-disposition as an attachement. I have no control at all over the sending server unfortunately but this works fine in a browser. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming request looks malformed. Transfer-Encoding is its own header name. You cannot assign it to the value of another header. And AFAIK, Content isn't even a standard HTTP header name.

Refer to the list at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Message_body_information for valid Content-* headers. The Transfer-Encoding header is documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding.

**Edit for framework 4.8 and below**

I had to add the following lines to app.config to let the client process invalid responses from the server.

```
<system.net>
  <settings>
    <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

The program itself is shown below.

```
try
{
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("http://localhost:9091");

    var attachment = new byte[1024];
    foreach (var h in response.Content.Headers)
    {
        var e = h.Value.GetEnumerator();
        e.MoveNext();
        attachment = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Current); // Convert UTF-8 encoded string into raw bytes

        Console.WriteLine($"{h.Key}, {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(attachment)}"); // Save raw bytes to disk instead of converting back to string and writing to Console
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

**Edit for dotnet core**

```
try
{
    var s = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    var a = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    await s.ConnectAsync(a, 9091);

    var request = "GET http://localhost:9091/";
    var outBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
    var outBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(outBytes);

    await s.SendAsync(outBuffer, SocketFlags.None);

    var inBytes = new byte[1024];
    var inBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(inBytes);
    await s.ReceiveAsync(inBuffer, SocketFlags.None);

    var r = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inBuffer.Array);
}
catch (SocketException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {exception.Message}");
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. That is what I am seeing in fiddler and it appears in the miscellaneous section rather than the entity section too. Unfortunately i'm not able to do anything about it as it's not my server, is there any way to have webclient (or httpclient, or anything else for that matter) just ignore the dodgy header?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to implement a file proxy. As long as the response has the file contents, you can still extract it manually. This could be a bit dodgy, but since you cannot reconfigure the other server, this is your best bet. I'm editing in some code into my answer above.

Comment: Using firefox dev I don't actuall see this header and the file downloads sucessfully but here is the raw request from fiddler:

HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2020 13:48:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment;fileName="1584712111087_1023_20200320115406_01926410022.wav";
Content-Description: JSP Generated Data
Content=Transfer-Encoding: binary

1ed6
RIFF8
 WAVEfmt      @   >    data@
Truncated for brevity

Comment: Looks like I might get some mileage out of useUnsafeHeaderParsing but can't work out where to put it in an mvc core application!

Comment: I'd love to add that to app.config but this is an MVC Core application so that doesn't exist! There's actually an issue that deals with this here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29927

Comment: The only way I can think of working around this is to use a binary socket. Then you can receive and parse any kind of response even if it doesn't follow the HTTP protocol standard. Edited a simple proof of concept in the answer above.